# Should I avoid authenticating the user unnecessarily to a server?

Tags: session-management

I’m thinking a RESTful client–server architecture. There will be routes that require users to authenticate before they can access the resource (e.g. creating or editing resources). Other resources are freely available—no authentication required.

I’m writing a frontend module to provide an abstraction from the request/response internals. Its job would be maintaining user state (once provided by the user) and sending the appropriate authentication headers.

Is it appropriate to send the authentication headers on every request? Or should the module be aware of which routes require authentication and only send the headers on those routes? Would the answer be different depending on whether I control the server or not?

Let’s assume for the sake of argument that the messages will be encrypted. Also note that I’m not intending to prompt the user for authentication whenever they access any route. I’m considering the case where the user has already provided authentication information for a previous request and now requests an unprotected resource.

Personally I cannot see a reason not to send the headers. If security were compromised by sending them, then that would also be the case where the headers *are* required. The added message length should not be worth considering. But then again, I don’t know the first thing about security, and spamming credentials doesn’t feel right to me.

Comment: Think about web applications. Once you log in, your cookies are sent to the server with every request, even if it doesn't require authentication (e.g. on the public homepage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Application complexity**

Let us assume that client uses a secure channel like TLS to communicate with server. Then, sending authentication info like tokens does not expose any sensitive data.

If you make the client decide when to send authentication info, it increases complexity of your application. Each time you change protected or unprotected routes on the server, or each time you add new protected or unprotected resources, you have to update the client. There will always be some probability that you don't send authentication info when server requires it.

**Header types**

You are talking about *authentication headers*. If you mean cookies, then it is fine. But if you mean that you have your own header type, then this can be a problem. Browsers send cookies related to particular domain / path automatically. You can be sure that the cookies set by your application will not be sent to some external domain.
Whereas if you use your own header type, there is some chance that you send your authentication headers also to external domains. The owner of the external domain can use it to attack your application. That's why I discourage you from using custom headers for authentication and use cookies instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I suspect you are confusing Authentication with Authorisation.

Read up on oAuth or similar authorisation frameworks. Dont engineer your own, unless you have no alternative option. Especially if your API will be publicly exposed.

I'd recommend looking into OWASP to understand the common mistakes people make (and how to avoid them).

https://owasp.org/www-project-cheat-sheets/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: I am well aware of the difference between authorization and authentication. My case considers authentication, i.e. proving to the server that the request stems from a specific user (who has previously provided their credentials to the frontend/server), even though it’s not required. Your link was helpful.

Comment: @Frank Jackson: The question is clearly about authentication. If you read *to prompt the user for authentication*, it is hard to imagine how would you ask user for *authorization*.